# What's a more efficient way to execute a function over a series of 2d subarrays from a 3d numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 3d numpy array of [3, 4, 3] like this

```
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
indices = np.array([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]])
primedata = data[indices]
stackdata = np.stack([primedata, primedata+1, primedata+2])
```

This will yield

```
[[[ 1,  2,  3],
  [ 2,  3,  4],
  [ 4,  5,  6],
  [ 6,  7,  8]],

 [[ 2,  3,  4],
  [ 3,  4,  5],
  [ 5,  6,  7],
  [ 7,  8,  9]],

 [[ 3,  4,  5],
  [ 4,  5,  6],
  [ 6,  7,  8],
  [ 8,  9, 10]]]
```

I want to operate on each of the 2d subarrays along the first axis. Such as this:

```
def _2dfunc(array):
    rands = np.random.randint(6, size=array.shape[1])
    mean = array.mean()
    result = (array * rands) - mean
    return result
    
processed = np.stack([_2dfunc(_2d) for _2d in stackdata ])
```

I like the result, but I suspect there are better ways to achieve it.

I tried using a vectorized function, but it receives individual numbers, not 2d arrays.

Comment: Don't use `np.vectorize` unless you read the whole docs, including the performance disclaimer.  And as you found, it is intended for functions that take scalar values.  For your function, either loop as you do, or change the function to work with the whole 3d array, taking full advantage of the shape and axis parameters of functions like `randint` and `mean`.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you have any recommendations on how to take that full advantage of shape and axis? I'm interested in performing arithmetic across rows and columns in the subarrays. It's a bit confusing for me at times. I've been experimenting and found out that I can't multiply shape (3,4,3) by a shape (3,3), but I can multiply a shape (4,3) by a shape (3), and then stack three of those achieving (3,4,3). It feels like I lack more structured understanding, but I can't discover the relevant information.

Comment: have you encountered `broadcasting` in your reading of numpy docs?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, thanks for pointing to that. I've read about broadcasting, but my knowledge is limited to what the official documentation provides. I am very interested in how to manipulate the arrays, where to add axes, in order to manipulate rows vs columns and such. I think I'll look maybe for python courses/tutorials covering it in more depth.

Answer (score 2):

Create `rands` with correct shape, then you can directly multiply it with `stackdata` without using a for loop:

```
i, _, k = stackdata.shape
rands = np.random.randint(6, size=i * k).reshape((i, 1, k))
stackdata * rands - stackdata.mean(axis=(1, 2))

array([[[-3.25, -3.25,  8.75],
        [-2.25, -2.25, 13.75],
        [-0.25, -0.25, 23.75],
        [ 1.75,  1.75, 33.75]],

       [[ 1.75, -2.25,  5.75],
        [ 4.75, -1.25,  8.75],
        [10.75,  0.75, 14.75],
        [16.75,  2.75, 20.75]],

       [[ 1.75,  2.75, 18.75],
        [ 3.75,  4.75, 23.75],
        [ 7.75,  8.75, 33.75],
        [11.75, 12.75, 43.75]]])
```